# How to prove differentiability

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ if the following function is differentiable at $x=1$.

$$ f(x)=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x^2 + 3x + a &  & x\le1, \\
bx + 2~~~~~~~~~ &  & x>1.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried equating the left-hand derivatives and right-hand derivatives. Moreover, i had some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a function to be differentiable at a point it's value at that point has to equal limit of that function at that point and derivatives from both sides must be the same. So in this case:\begin{aligned}x^2 + 3x + a = bx + 2\end{aligned}\begin{aligned}2x + 3 = b\end{aligned}
By plugging in 1 you can easily get that *a* equals 3, and *b* equals 5.

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused before.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to make one-sided limits equal to each other (for continuity purposes) and make one-sided derivatives equal to each other. So we have the conditions: $4+a=b+2$ (for limits) and $b=5$ (for derivatives). Then $a=3,b=5$.